# iTextSharp generating pdfs, compiles and runs without error but no PDF appears

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, itext

I've tried a number of different variations to output a very basic PDF from memory but all seem to return the same result, which is to say it doesn't actually return anything. The code compiles and runs without error but when VS finishes processing the code nothing happens.

I'm using VS2008 and iTextSharp v5.1.1

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Here is my code in its current state:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();           
Document doc = new Document();        
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
writer.CloseStream = false;

doc.Open();
doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test Content"));
doc.Add(new Paragraph(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
doc.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);
Response.OutputStream.Flush();            
Response.OutputStream.Close();
ms.Close();
```

Comment: There's a good working version here: http://bit.ly/kEWMWn.
Might be worth your while to compare your attempt with it to see if you're missing anything.

I can't remember if iTextSharp writes to an error log - might be worth checking that too if so.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your suggestion. There were some differences, unfortunately none of which made any difference to the result I'm receiving. Could the issue perhaps have anything to do with the browser I'm using? I'm currently running IE9, but am unable to test in other browsers as the website has been written to be browser specific to IE only.

Comment: I think it might be worth testing with other browsers if you can, but I would have thought its more likely to be a serverside issue.

Does your code throw any exceptions? Can you step through it in the debugger? And is there an error log you can look at?

Comment: Ok, the code does not throw any exceptions and I have stepped through it multiple times (everytime I change something infact), which is why it's quite confusing. There don't appear to be any logs, none of which I can see anyway. I am using third party logging but as VS isn't throwing any errors those logs are clear.

Comment: Edit: I have managed to test in Chrome, which results in the exact same issue.

Comment: Tried same code and same dll with framework 3.5 and 4.0... it works properly in chrome, firefox and ie!

Comment: Hmmm, I can't understand it then. Is there anything else I could be doing wrong? Or anything else that could be set up incorrectly, e.g. IIS or something like that? Many thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried doing `Response.Clear()` before you write the pdf to the response?  You may be getting some page markup at the beginning of the stream which is confusing the browser.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried completely clearing the response, content and headers. Have just tried on a colleagues machine using a blank website which worked exactly as it should. This leads me to believe it has something to do with IIS. I've also tried giving temporary full access to all users to exclude the possibility of it being a permissions related issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing my issue, the code was in a button_click event where the button control was inside an ajax update panel, as soon as i moved the button outside of the update panel it worked perfectly. Not sure if this is a fundamental mistake on my part or a bug with update panels so I'm off to have a read about them.

@Mark Storer, I appreciate now that this wasn't an ITextSharp problem, however when I wrote this I believed it to be, apologies to all for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I learned early on, don't use `GetBuffer()`, use `ToArray()`. See this post:

[iTextSharp-generated PDFs now cause Save dialog in Adobe Reader X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109384/itextsharp-generated-pdfs-now-cause-save-dialog-in-adobe-reader-x/5119739#5119739)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've just tried this and didn't make any difference. I'm sure this is IIS related and not code related, as all variations of code seem to end in the same result. I've already checked mimetypes and allowed filenameextensions but there muast be something else.

Comment: There's been a development... I've just created a brand new website on my local machine to test the code, which works! But for some reason it just will not work in my actual project.

Comment: Then this isn't an iText problem, it's a `Response` problem.  I suggest you retag appropriately.