# Creating a PDF with itextsharp works fine in development but fails when deployed to IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, itext

I am deploying and testing an application using IIS 7. It creates a PDF using ITextSharp, which works fine when running from VS2010. When running from IIS, I get an error: The document has no pages.
Using the same data with the VS2010 development server, the PDF is printed OK. The error has nothing to do with a lack of pages.
The itextsharp.dll is included in the bin folder under the IIS Web Site.
What am I missing?

Here is my code (though I do not tjhink it is relevant);

```
    protected void TextSharpMethod()
    {
        // get order details
        #region getOrdersData
        var ordersData = DataAccessLayer.OrdersDataHelpers.getOrderDataByOrderId(_intOrderId);

        #endregion


        if (ordersData != null)
        {
            #region getSupplierDetails
            // get supplier details
            var rowSupplier = (from s in _dataContextOrders.FMSSuppliers
                               where s.ID == ordersData.SupplierID
                               select new
                                   {
                                       s.ID,
                                       s.CommonShortName,
                                       s.ExternalRef,
                                       s.Name,
                                       s.Address,
                                       s.SupplierDetail.Telephone,
                                       s.SupplierDetail.WebAddress,
                                       s.SupplierDetail.Email,
                                       s.SupplierDetail.Fax
                                   }).FirstOrDefault();
            #endregion

            #region getOrderLineData
            var orderLineData = (from ol in _dataContextOrders.OrderLines
                                 join o in _dataContextOrders.Orders on ol.OrderID equals o.ID
                                 join ec in _dataContextOrders.FMSExpenseCodes on ol.OrderLineExpenseCodeID equals ec.ID into group1
                                 from g1 in group1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 join cc in _dataContextOrders.FMSCostCentres on ol.OrderLineCostCentreID equals cc.ID into group2
                                 from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 select new
                                     {
                                         ol.ID,
                                         ol.OrderID,
                                         ol.OrderLineNumber,
                                         ol.OrderLineQty,
                                         ol.OrderLineDescription,
                                         ol.OrderLineUnitCost,
                                         ol.OrderLineUnitTax,
                                         ol.OrderLineTotal,
                                         ol.OrderLineExpenseCodeID,
                                         ol.GoodsReceivedQty,
                                         ol.InvoicedQty,
                                         ol.OrderLineCostCentreID,
                                         ol.OrderLineVatRate,
                                         ol.OrderLineUnitGross,

                                         ExpenseCode = g1.ExternalRef == null ? "" : g1.ExternalRef,
                                         CostCodeRef = g2.ExternalRef == null ? "" : g2.ExternalRef
                                     }).Where(ol => ol.OrderID == _intOrderId).OrderBy(ol => ol.OrderLineNumber);
            #endregion

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30))
            using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms))
            {
                document.AddCreator("SVSIT");
                document.AddTitle("PURCHASE ORDER");
                document.Open();

                #region setupPdfDoc

                // LOGO
                string path = Server.MapPath("/");

                string imageLocation = path + "/Images/southView_integration_logo_applications.jpg";
                imageLocation = imageLocation.Replace("\\", "/");
                iTextSharp.text.Image bmp =
                    iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageLocation);
                // caution - image may not work if app is moved
                bmp.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                bmp.ScalePercent(50f);
                document.Add(bmp);

                // COMPANY ADDRESS

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
                PdfPCell cell;
                //actual width of table in points (A4=595points)
                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;

                float[] widths = new float[] {2.75f, 2.75f};
                table.SetWidths(widths);
                // 0=no border, 1=border
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                PdfBlankCell(table);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "PURCHASE ORDER", _bold);
                PdfBlankCell(table);


                float flXPos = 842; // 842 - height of A4 in points
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // CONTACT PERSON
                table = new PdfPTable(4);
                //actual width of table in points (A4=595points)

                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;

                widths = new float[] {1f, 1.75f, 1.35f, 1.35f};
                table.SetWidths(widths);
                // 0=no border, 1=border
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Contact Person", _norm);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, ordersData.OrderContactName, _norm);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Tel: " + ordersData.OrderContactTel, _norm);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Fax: " + ordersData.OrderContactFax, _norm);

                flXPos = 715;
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // SUPPLIER DETAILS

                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 270f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1; // has border
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "To (Supplier)", _bold);

                table.AddCell(ordersData.SupplierName);

                if (rowSupplier != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(rowSupplier.Address); // might want to break this up by line breaks
                }
                else
                {
                    table.AddCell(" ");
                }

                flXPos = 695;
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // ORDER NO
                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 275f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;


                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Order No: " + ordersData.PORef + " / 100630", _bold);

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _bold);
                PdfBlankCell(table);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Date: " + ordersData.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString (), _bold);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Your ref: " + ordersData.OtherRef, _bold);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "PURCHASE ORDER NUMBER MUST BE", _bold);

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthBottom = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "QUOTED ON INVOICE TO ENSURE PAYMENT", _bold);


                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left + 275, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);
                flXPos = 595;

                // DELIVERY ADDRESS

                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 270f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1; // has border
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Delivery Address:", _bold);

                table.AddCell(ordersData.DeliveryContactName);

                table.AddCell(ordersData.DeliveryAddress);



                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // INVOICE ADDRESS

                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 275f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Invoice Address:", _bold);

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "          CVCHA", _norm);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "          11 High Street", _norm);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "          Castle Vale", _norm);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "          Birmingham", _norm);

                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthTop = 0;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthLeft = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthRight = 1;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidthBottom = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "          B35 7PR", _norm);

                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left + 275, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // ORDER LINES

                table = new PdfPTable(5);
                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                widths = new float[] {2.70f, .7f, .7f, .7f, .7f};
                table.SetWidths(widths);
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Description", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Code", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Quantity", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Unit Cost", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Total Cost", _bold);
                // 13 rows
                // get order lines data
                int i1 = 0;
                foreach (var orderLine in orderLineData)
                {
                    if (orderLine != null)
                    {
                        PdfAddTableCell(table, orderLine.OrderLineDescription, _norm);
                        PdfAddTableCell(table, orderLine .CostCodeRef +", " + orderLine.ExpenseCode , _norm); // code - to do
                        PdfAlignRightTableCell(table, orderLine.OrderLineQty.ToString(), _norm);
                        PdfAlignRightTableCell (table, orderLine.OrderLineUnitCost.ToString(), _norm);
                        PdfAlignRightTableCell(table, orderLine.OrderLineTotal.ToString(), _norm);
                        i1++;
                    }
                }
                // fill remaining grid
                for (int i = i1; i <= 13; i++)
                {
                    PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _norm);
                    PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _norm);
                    PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _norm);
                    PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _norm);
                    PdfAddTableCell(table, " ", _norm);
                }

                // DELIVERY DATE / TOTAL LINE


                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Required Delivery Date: " + ordersData.ExpectedDeliveryDate, _bold);

                _chunk = new Chunk("Total:                £", _bold );
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_chunk));
                cell.Colspan = 3;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                _chunk = new Chunk(ordersData.TotalAmount.ToString("0.00"), _bold);
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(_chunk));
                cell.Colspan = 1;

                table.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment  = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                table.AddCell(cell);

                flXPos = 490;
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // PREPARED BY / AUTHORISED BY

                table = new PdfPTable(3);
                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                widths = new float[] {1.83f, 1.83f, 1.83f};
                table.SetWidths(widths);
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Prepared By:" + "", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Signature:" + "", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Date:" + "", _bold);

                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Authorised By:" + "", _bold); // ApproverPersonID
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Signature:" + "", _bold);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Date:" + "", _bold);

                flXPos = 195;
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                // FOOTER

                table = new PdfPTable(1);
                table.TotalWidth = 550f;
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Distibution of Copies", _norm);
                PdfAddTableCell(table,
                                "1. White - Supplier     2. Yellow - Finance Section     3. Pink - Originator (Budget Holder)",
                                _norm);
                PdfAddTableCell(table, "Industrial & Provident Society No. 28414R     Housing Corporation No. L4118",
                                _norm);

                flXPos = 95;
                table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, flXPos, writer.DirectContent);

                #endregion

                document.Close();
                writer.Close();

                #region writeToDatabase

                MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());

                WritePdfToDatabase(ms2);

                #endregion

                Response.ContentType = "pdf/application";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=PurchaseOrder.pdf");
                Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);

            }
        }
    }

    protected void WritePdfToDatabase(MemoryStream ms2)
    {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms2);
        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)ms2.Length);
        br.Close();

        DocumentsDataHelper.UpdateDocument(bytes, "pdf/application", "Purchase Order",_intOrderId ,1);
    }


    protected void PdfBlankCell(PdfPTable table)
    {
        _chunk = new Chunk("", _norm);
        _phrase = new Phrase(_chunk);
        table.AddCell(_phrase);
    }

    protected void PdfAddTableCell(PdfPTable table, string s, Font f)
    {
        _chunk = new Chunk(s, f);
        _phrase = new Phrase(_chunk);
        table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        table.AddCell(_phrase);
    }
    protected void PdfAlignRightTableCell(PdfPTable table, string s, Font f)
    {
        _chunk = new Chunk(s, f);
        _phrase = new Phrase(_chunk);
        table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
        table.AddCell(_phrase);
    }
    protected void PdfTableFieldAndHeader(string heading, string value, PdfPTable table)
    {
        PdfAddTableCell(table, heading, _bold);
        PdfAddTableCell(table, value, _norm);
    }
    protected void PdfBoldAndNormLine(string text1, string text2, Document document)
    {

        Chunk c1 = new Chunk(text1, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
        Chunk c2 = new Chunk(text2, FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 12.0f, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL));
        Phrase p1 = new Phrase();
        p1.Add(c1);
        p1.Add(c2);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

        p.Add(p1);
        p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        document.Add(p);
    }
```

Comment: Without code we can't help you too much. But generally speaking, "no pages" means nothing was added to the document. Are you parsing HTML from a URL by chance?

Comment: I repeat: Using the same data with the VS2010 development server, the PDF is printed OK. It is not a code problem.

Comment: Steve, I'm just trying to help, your question doesn't really tell us anything so I'm going on what I've seen in the past. All you are saying is "Something works here but not over there." What is your data? Is it a database, a text file, literal text baked into your code? We've ruled out HTML from a URL at least (a situation that I have seen break between development and live servers many times). And how are you adding your "data" to the PDF?

Comment: I did not add the code because it did not seem relevant. It is also very bulky, maybe 400 + lines of code. The data is coming from a database - the same database that I was using in development. The rest of the application, whcih also uses the same database, is fine.

Comment: Dayum. The error was in my code! I commented out the paragraph that adds an image. Then it worked. Sorry. The problem is obviously in my relative addressing.

Comment: Good to hear! Also, you should change the line `Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, ms.GetBuffer().Length);` to use `ToArray()` instead or you'll end up with corrupt PDFs every once in a while, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5119739/231316